# Socket.io implementation in Next.js 14.1.0 app directory

Tags: socket.io, next.js14, socket.io-client

I want to implement a video conference app where I need to implement socket connection for specific rooms. Since `Next.js` is a serverless framework, I had to create a default `GET` method and initialize the socket server and assigning it to `NextResponse` as a property.

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

export async function GET(req, res) {
  if (res.socketio) {
    console.log('socket already running');
    return res;
  }
  res = new NextResponse();
  const io = new Server({
    path: '/api/socket.io',
    addTrailingSlash: false,
  });
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('socket id: ', socket.id);
    socket.emit('welcome: ', socket.id);
    socket.on('message', (message) => {
      console.log(message);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('socket is disconnecting');
    });
  });
  res.socketio = io;
  return res;
}
```

And calling the `io` from the client.

```js
'use client';

import io from 'socket.io-client';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Home() {
  const socket = io();
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('message', message);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchIO = async () => await fetch('/api/socket.io');
    fetchIO();
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
        <input
          className="border"
          type="text"
          name="message"
          value={message}
          onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

But the problem I am facing is getting continuous `GET 404 not found error`.

[image: error sample]

Can you please tell me what I am missing? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

I am expecting to read the socket in the client from the server and vice-varsa.

N.B: I want to implement both of client and server functionality on the same server. Thank you :)

Comment: found any solution? if yes please share!

Comment: @dev1ce As far as I googled and searched online, there's no solution for socket programming with next.js 14 app router yet. If you need to implement socket programming in your app, try with next.js 13 or go with express for your dedicated backend service.

Comment: Yes, i had to create a separate socket server with node & express... Thanks anyway!